# How to handle null timestamps using coalesce in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have three columns with datatype TIMESTAMP(6) and I wish to find out the minimum of the three timestamps. At any given time, there will be at least 1 non-null data point among the three columns.

I tried finding an alternative online but couldn't find anything related to timestamp comparison on this matter. There is a solution of using coalesce which works on data type date but not on timestamps.

Comment: Coalescing a timestamp seems to work for me: `SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP(0)), TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 05:00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are asking about trying to use `LEAST` with timestamps? I don't know why Teradata hasn't done anything about that.  For timestamps, I just cast them as varchar.  Nulls make it uglier, because you have to coalesce them with something, depending on if you want null to be less than everything else or not.

```
select
least (
coalesce(null,'9999-12-31'),        --if you want nulls to not be the least
cast(current_timestamp as varchar(32)),
cast(timestamp '2018-01-01 05:00:00' as varchar(32)))
```

In a real query, you'll end up combining coalesce and cast for every column you want to feed into the least function.

EDIT:
I should probably add that this works on YYYY-MM-DD dates, other formats may not sort correctly.